# Reduce a ratio to its lowest terms. Prolog

Tags: prolog, reduction

Hi guys first time on here ^.^ Exams are soon coming up and I started to work out some past papers. I stumbled upon the following question and unfortunately I don't have any answers for this question.

The question is as follows:
rRatio(OriginalRatio, FinalRatio) that reduces the OriginalRatio to its lowest term and binds it to the FinalRatio (ie, 30:10:20 is the same as 3:1:2 ).

From what I have thought and worked out so far is that I need to make use of a GCD and here's it's code as follows:

```
gcd(0, X, X) :-!.
gcd(X, 0, X) :-!.
gcd(X, X, X) :-!.
gcd(M, N, X) :- N>M, Y is N-M, gcd(M, Y, X).
gcd(M, N, X) :- N<M, Y is M-N, gcd(Y, N, X).
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you know in general, independent of Prolog, how to reduce a numerator and denominator pair to lowest terms using their gcd? Not clear what you're asking here.

Comment: Yes of course. Could you please tell me what's not clear? Thanks

Comment: It wasn't clear from your original question whether you understood what needed to be done versus how to do it in Prolog. And if Prolog, whether you just don't know how to represent the ratios, or how to do the arithmetic in Prolog. Or do you need a Prolog tutorial (which is not what this site is for). If you've tried to implement `rRation(OriginalRatio, FinalRatio)` and are stuck on a specific point, then you should ask a more specific question.

Comment: Colon is a standard operator, so you can start with `rRatio(A:B:C,D:E:F) :-`

Comment: Hi Lurker what I'm stuck on is hw to do it in prolog. That is functions etc shall I use?
My attempt and reasoning was since that I need for instance ratio(30,10,20) I need to have an output that displays a ratio of (3,1,2). Here is how I'm imagining the output to be: `rRatio(ratio([40,10,20]),R). binds R to ratio([4,1,2]).`

Hope this clears things and you might be able to help :) Thanks @lurker